# Need to learn Oracle Forms 6.0, can't setup environment

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle8i

I have [Oracle Forms Interactive Workbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130158089), and it looks like a good tutorial, but I can't setup environment to do exercises (book uses Oracle Developer 6.0 & Oracle8).

I installed [Oracle Forms 6i](http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/forms/6i_rel2_xp.zip) and Oracle Express database 10g, but Forms 6i crashes, when I try to connect from it to 10g.

- can I get Oracle 8 somewhere?
- anybody knows how to reconcile Forms 6i with 10g?

**UPDATE:** modern alternatives, like ApEx aren't a solution, because 6th version is used among other developers.

**UPDATE2:** sorry for previous title of the question, it was misleading

Answer (score 1):

Forms 6i works perfectly fine with 10g. I would recommend against hunting down 8i and using that. The database is not your problem.

That said, it's hard to know how to help without more specific information. Are you trying to use the forms server? Does Forms builder crash, or is it Forms Runtime? Any messages? What components did you install - did you do a custom install or a typical?

Comment: Forms 6i doesn't work with 10g for some charactersets. There's probably a bunch of patchsets that need to be applied to any base install too (which will require a metalink support account for the relevant product)

Answer (score 1):

You can use oracle forms 6i / 6 with any oracle database. I have used it with oracle 8,9i, 10g. Install any avalialbe database and start working. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The modern equivalent is Oracle Application Express (aka APEX, formerly HTML DB). It normally comes bundled with Oracle Database 11g. It is a thin web-based client rather than a client application a la Forms.

More information: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html

Comment: This is a modern alternative to Forms (and a very good one), but if the OP needs to learn Forms (e.g. for his/her job) then it won't help.